# Validating form with JavaScript that is in a separate header

Tags: javascript

I have a [php](/questions/tagged/php)website that includes a header and footer on every page. On one of my pages I have a form called **"orderForm"** and onSubmit is equal to **"return(validate())"**. In my header (which gets included on that page) I have a function called **function validate()**.

My problem is trying to validate the order form from my header file. I know it partly works when my validate function consists of:

```
alert("Test");
return false;
```

As I get an alert when I submit the form.

But when I try something like:

```
if (document.orderForm.postcode.value.length < 1) {
    alert("Postcode field cannot be empty.");
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't validate it, despite **orderForm** and **postcode** being the correct names of the form fields. Is this because I am including the header file while having the form in a different file?

Cheers

Comment: Show your javascript function code here. So we can check your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test by name you can do this, assuming no other onload code in the page. The main point is to wait with assigning the validation until after the form exists on the page.

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.orderForm.onsubmit=function() {
    if (this.postcode.value.length < 1) {
        alert("Postcode field cannot be empty.");
        return false; //cancel submission
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
}
```

To use preventDefault with my code you can try

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.orderForm.onsubmit=function(e) {
    var event=e?e:window.event; 
    if (this.postcode.value.length < 1) {
        alert("Postcode field cannot be empty.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I must comment that the use of "return false" does not ensure 100% that the default action is prevented form submission, therefore, the right thing would be using preventDefault ().

Here a reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Thanks for this, it works! Not sure why you were downvoted though. Cheers.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez The only known situation where preventDefault works better than return false is when you have an error in your code before the return false is reached. Also return false works in all known jsenabled browsers, preventDefault will not work in older browsers which alas still are plentyfull

Comment: Oh, that's really true.
In older browsers the statement «return false» will successfully work.
Thank you very much for the information. Today I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the «name» attribute in the form and the input tag.

In this scenario you must ensure that the fields are loaded on the page with window.onload.
You can assign a submit event to your form. In this context you can run your script to validate your field.

You must prevent the default action of the form with preventDefault().

This is the solution:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("orderForm");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    if (document.orderForm.postcode.value.length < 1) {
      e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the default action to submit the form to the server.
      alert("Postcode field cannot be empty.");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" name="orderForm">
  <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is not how to test onsubmit

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. I'm gonna fix it. Thanks.

Comment: That will execute immediately, even if the form is not yet on the page which is likely since the function validate currently lives in the head

Comment: The perfect way is using window.onload.

Comment: I agree. And now your answer looks more and more like my answer